# PHP External API

Tags: php, api

I'm looking to build an API that users can call, so that they can integrate our app with their own processes. Most of the database and php models have already been created.

I'm looking for a tutorial with examples on the best way to accomplish this. Must include all the security considerations as well.

I'd like to use an established framework to assist with this - so far CodeIgniter has caught my eye as being the easiest to get to grips with. I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: Does your API need authentication? If not the best thing to do is make an api.php that accepts URL parameters and returns delicious JSON.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967991/web-service-construction-toolkit-wrapper-for-php

Comment: I am going to suggest Zend Framework. I have had this bookmarked for a while, maybe it is of some use http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/building-restful-zend-framework-applications

Comment: Yep, definitely needs authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial that explains you the basics to do it yourself:
http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Or if you're more comfortable with a framework Recess is a nice one to consider:
http://www.recessframework.org/